# CAP Theorem x Load Balance / Failover x Availability

Tags: high-performance, distributed-system

My understanding is that the system below can accomplish consistency, availability and partition tolerance. So I must be misinterpreting some aspect of the CAP theorem. How come?

Let's say I have a distributed system with 100 redundant nodes: 50 in a datacenter in the US and 50 in a datacenter in Europe. These two datacenters are connected through a dedicated link. At some point this link breaks and there is a clear network partition. The nodes in Europe can immediately determine that their link to the US is now broken and change their state to unavailable. As a result, request arriving in Europe are re-routed by the load-balancer to the US. My question is:

- Can this system be considered highly-available?
- In regards to the CAP theorem, what am I not accomplishing: consistency, availability or partitioning tolerance?

Comment: What you have described is not a true partitioning -- if requests to Europe can be redirected by a load balancer to the US, then so can the operations of the European network. You also don't allow for the amount of time to recognize "partitioning", nor do you describe the recovery that follows the network outage. So, no, just because you wave your hands in the air doesn't mean you've solved anything.

Comment: You might want to read up on the [Fallacies of distributed computing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fallacies_of_distributed_computing)

Comment: @BobDalgleish I have the best intentions here. There is a link between Europe and US. If it is broken there is nothing you can do. The time to recognize partitioning is the configurable heartbeat time of this link. Perhaps load-balancing and failover is not allowed/compatible when you have network partitioning, at least for the CAP theorem definition.

Comment: @BobDalgleish Also when you say "*if requests to Europe can be redirected by a load balancer to the US, then so can the operations of the European network*", that's not true. Clients can access the system through the internet. But the distributed system itself has to rely on this link for inter-datacenter communication. **The load balancer redirects. It does not forward.**

Comment: Looks like [today is CAP day](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/329020/1352).

Comment: CAP doesn't talk about dedicated links, so that scenario is outside of CAP.

Answer (score 2):

You've broken availability.  Computers are not omniscient.  They can't "immediately determine their link to the US is broken."  All they can determine is they are no longer receiving responses to their packets.  This could be caused by the link being broken **or** it could be caused by the other datacenter being down.  Congratulations, you've just marked your only good datacenter as unavailable, and instructed your load balancer to direct all traffic to the data center that just exploded.

Comment: Hummm. You have a good point. But the whole datacenter being down is kind of very unlikely. If there is no response on the link, you should assume that the link is down, not the whole datacenter. No?

Comment: Here is a good explanation: https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html